# Eclipse Indigo SR2 ships with m2e, do i need to install something more?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-indigo, m2e

when you install eclispe indigo SR2, m2e seems already install, you can acces the "Maven repositories" tab ...
But when i check on the market place for "maven", eclipse tells me i could install 2 new plugin :
1-Maven Integration for WTP
Maven integration for WTP (aka m2e-wtp) aims at providing a tight 
integration between Maven Integration for Eclipse (aka m2e) and the eclipse Web ...

2-Maven Integration for eclipse
m2e provide comprehensive Maven Integration for eclipse. You can use m2e to manage both simple 
and multi modules Maven projects, ....

This is very confusing.

What do I really need ?
I am using WTP and JBoss Tools 3.3

Answer (score 1):

1 - If you really want to integrate your JBoss environnement in eclipse (e.g. launch it from eclipse, enable autodeploy, ...), m2e-wtp will really help you. Maven hold the lifecycle of your app (compile, package, ...) and dependencies in classpath.
Without the plugin you will probably face of classpath issues for instance, or inconsistent deployed war.

This is what Maven Integration for WTP is intended for.

2 - I'm not sure of each plugin roles, but this one will add some extra features / extra menu, over m2e, wich offer "basic features" (really more than basic indeed). Maven Integration for eclipse m2e would probably add smoothes features. I don't know if you really need it. I think you should, but you can do without it.